# I want to inject XSS payload in an anchor tag, but the double quotes are being converted into %22

Tags: xss

The tag works like this:

```
<a ref="http://googl.com%22 onclick=alert(124)">http://google.com" onclick=alert(124)</a>
```

Here, the double quote I put is turned into `%22`. Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: did you try single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

> Here, the double quote I put is turned into `%22`. Is there a way to overcome it?

No. Double quotes changing into `%22` is called url encoding, which is performed so that rendered page doesn't treat it as double quotes.